# ionic 3 build VirtualStats stopped

Tags: ionic-framework

Yesterday my app was working fine on browser but now I get an error:

```
[21:01:05]  transpile started ...
[21:01:11]  typescript: .../feederhorgasz/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/virtual-file-utils.d.ts, line: 3
            Class 'VirtualStats' incorrectly implements interface 'Stats'. Property 'atimeMs' is missing in type
            'VirtualStats'.

       L2:  export declare class VirtualStats implements Stats {
       L3:      protected _path: string;
       L4:      protected _ctime: Date;

Error: Failed to transpile program
    at BuildError.Error (native)
    at new BuildError (C:\Users\Thomas\mobiledevelopment\feederhorgasz\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
    at C:\Users\Thomas\mobiledevelopment\feederhorgasz\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:159:20
    at transpileWorker (C:\Users\Thomas\mobiledevelopment\feederhorgasz\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:107:12)
    at Object.transpile (C:\Users\Thomas\mobiledevelopment\feederhorgasz\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:64:12)
    at C:\Users\Thomas\mobiledevelopment\feederhorgasz\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:106:82
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this code on Your project folder\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\virtual-file-utils.d.ts

```
readonly atimeMs: any;
readonly mtimeMs: any;
readonly ctimeMs: any;
readonly birthtimeMs: any;
```